# What word describes the woman who behaves like the man?

Tags: word-request

I want to know what word could precisely describe the woman who behaves like the man, doing his behavior, moving like him, getting interested in what interests

Comment: This can be a sensitive subject.  There are a lot of ways to express this, some neutral, some derogatory.  What exactly are you trying to say?

Comment: Have you considered the term **tomboy**?

Comment: It's possible OP means a specific man, and is talking about **mirroring** as an IoI.

Comment: A **copycat** could apply to any gender.

Comment: In the question, "the man" is confusing me. What man are you talking about? Her husband? boyfriend? If you mean "a man" (she behaves like men do) then you could say her behavior is **masculine** or, as Cookie Monster says, you can say she is a **tomboy**. But neither word is as extreme as I believe your question is implying. **butch**, a noun or adjective, refers to a lesbian whose appearance and behavior are seen as traditionally masculine, though I'm not sure whether it is considered offensive.

Comment: I referred to “man in general” by using “the man”... I think “tomboy” is closer than other words to the word I have been looking for. @Readin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under the reasonable assumption that you're talking about women in general and not about any particular woman that you might have in mind as this has been confusing for some people here, the expression that comes closest to what you're looking for and yet is still in common use would probably be [**tomboy**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tomboy). Although this term normally only applies to young girls whose social behavior is similar to that typically attributed to boys, it can be used in certain situations to describe adult women who in their manners exhibit qualities that are usually associated with grown men.

Example:

> She has been **a tomboy** her entire life. She always hangs out with men and enjoys rowdy activities like car riding and drinking beer.

You also might find interesting the Wikipedia page on [**metrosexuality**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metrosexual) (metrosexuals are men who enjoy activities that are considered feminine such as shopping, fashion and things like that). Just see what they've got to say about [**"female metrosexuals"**](https://ask.metafilter.com/11640/Female-Metrosexuals) under the subsection **female metrosexuality**.